# How does Lens (Kubernetes IDE) get direct shell access to Kubernetes nodes without ssh keys?

Tags: kubernetes

I couldn't find an equivalent k8s cli command to do something like this, nor any ssh keys stored as k8s secrets. It also appears to do this in a cloud-agnostic fashion.

Is it just using a k8s pod with special privileges or something?

Edit: oops, it's open-source. I'll investigate and update this question accordingly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Posting this community wiki answer to give more visibility on the comment that was made at a github issue that addressed this question:

> Lens will create `nsenter` pod to the selected node
>
> > ```
> > protected async createNodeShellPod(podId: string, nodeName: string) { 
> >   const kc = this.getKubeConfig(); 
> >   const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api); 
> >   const pod = { 
> >     metadata: { 
> >       name: podId, 
> >       namespace: "kube-system" 
> >     }, 
> >     spec: { 
> >       restartPolicy: "Never", 
> >       terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0, 
> >       hostPID: true, 
> >       hostIPC: true, 
> >       hostNetwork: true, 
> >       tolerations: [{ 
> >         operator: "Exists" 
> >       }], 
> >       containers: [{ 
> >         name: "shell", 
> >         image: "docker.io/alpine:3.9", 
> >         securityContext: { 
> >           privileged: true, 
> >         }, 
> >         command: ["nsenter"], 
> >         args: ["-t", "1", "-m", "-u", "-i", "-n", "sleep", "14000"] 
> >       }], 
> >       nodeSelector: { 
> >         "kubernetes.io/hostname": nodeName 
> >       } 
> >     } 
> >   } as k8s.V1Pod;
> > ```
>
> and exec into that container in lens terminal.
>
> -- *[Github.com: Lensapp: Issues: How Lens accessing nodes in AKS/EKS without user and SSH key under ROOT?](https://github.com/lensapp/lens/issues/824#issuecomment-688826431)*

---

I've checked this and as it can be seen below the `Pod` with `nsenter` is created in the `kube-system` (checked on `GKE`):

- `$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system` (output redacted)

```sh
kube-system   node-shell-09f6baaf-dc4a-4faa-969e-8016490eb8e0             1/1     Running   0          10m
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Github.com: Lensapp: Lens: Issues: How does lens use terminal/ssh for worker nodes?](https://github.com/lensapp/lens/issues/295)*
- *[Man7.org: Linux: Man pages: Nsenter](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html)*

Answer (score 2):

to build upon the answer from @dawid-kruk, here is a minimal example, to start a node-debug-shell pod using kubectl:

1. create the manifest file `node-debug-shell.yml`, being sure to update `nodeName` to match the desired node you wish to connect to:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: node-debug-shell
   spec:
     nodeName: <<hostname>>
     hostNetwork: true
     hostPID: true
     hostIPC: true

     containers:
       - name: node-debug-shell
         image: docker.io/alpine:3.13
         command:
           - nsenter
         args:
           - '-t'
           - '1'
           - '-m'
           - '-u'
           - '-i'
           - '-n'
           - sleep
           - '14000'
         securityContext:
           privileged: true
   ```
2. create the pod with kubectl:

   ```
   kubectl create -f node-debug-shell.yml
   ```
3. connect and access the shell within the new pod:

   ```
   kubectl exec -it node-debug-shell -- bash
   ```